# Google Cloud Console CPU Used Finding Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-compute-engine, gke-networking

I have a GCP project where I create a 2 GKE cluster.

1. CluserA (2 node, 8 Core CPU). Total 16 Core Used.
2. ClusterB (0 node, 0 Core CPU). Can Not Create or Scale Up node for limitation of limitation of quota.

Now, My Question is that, My Quota limit is 32 and i can not create any more node. when i have more 16 CPU exist.
I check my VM instances. There is no more VM who can usages my CPU cores.

How can i resolve this issues and find who usages my rest 16 core ? Here i attach some screen shot.

According to Current Usages,
[image]

According to CPU,
[image]

Total VM in My Project,
[image]
both of them 8 Core CPU (Machine type: e2-standard-8).

In this situation, I can not create no more node when i do not used yet more then 16 Core CPU.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot but sorting by `Current usage`?

Comment: I attached ss according to Current Usage..

Comment: Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm that you are not using an `autoscaler` or `automation script` as it will automatically scale the deployment so the quotas have been used by them.

Below mentioned points will help you:

1. Are you trying to create a cluster with `0 nodes` as it is not possible as the total number of nodes in the cluster must be at least 1, try creating a `1 node cluster`.
2. I can see your cpu limit across all `regions` is exceeded so as a workaround you can request an **increase of quota** in the same quota page, once you get the approval you will have revised quota limits so that you can create a cluster.

The consumption of other 16 cpus is not visible in the console so i will dig on this further and will provide an update if there any issue from google side i will give you a link to raise a request or i will raise a request on behalf of you and provide the link to track the status of the issue.

Note:  From this [Allocation quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/resource-usage#allocation_quotas_2)

> VM quotas are managed at the regional level. VM instance, instance group, disk quotas, and CPU can be consumed by any VM in the region, regardless of zone. For example, CPU quota is a regional quota, so there is a different limit and usage count for each region. To launch an n2-standard-16 instance in any zone in the us-central1 region, you need enough quota for at least 16 CPUs in us-central1.

From [CPU quota limits](https://cloud.google.com/compute/resource-usage#cpu_quota):

> To help protect Compute Engine systems and other users, some new accounts and projects also have a global CPUs (All Regions) quota. That quota applies to all regions and is measured as a sum of all your vCPUs in all regions. For example, if you have 48 vCPUs remaining in a single region such as us-central1 but only 32 vCPUs remaining for the CPUs (All Regions) quota, you can launch only 32 vCPUs in the us-central1 region, even though there is remaining quota in the region. This is because you reach the CPU (All Regions) quota and need to delete existing instances before you can launch new instances.